# How do I re-install packages that were installed with an unofficial source with the one from the official source? (apt, debian 10)

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I used the sury repository to install a few packages (php5.6) but now I don't need it and use php7.3 (which the latter is in the official repositories but 5.6 needed unofficial repositories).
While using the sury repository, I upgraded the system with `# apt upgrade`, and some packages wanted to be re-installed with the sury version. I want to re-install these packages but with the official repository (security.debian.org) so I can remove sury.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to the sury repository but may be reproducible with other repositories.

For buster, sury uses +debian10 in all their package versions compared to vanilla debian which either uses deb10 or nothing added.

So you can do `sudo apt list --installed|grep -i debian10` or similar to find packages installed with sury.

Do `apt-cache policy (each package in the list)` and find the vanilla repository one (usually {security,cdn}.debian.org with the standard mirrors).

Do `apt reinstall (package)=(package version of vanilla one)` and it will install the vanilla one.

Once you have no more packages listed in the list command, there are no more packages from the sury repository.